# too many arguments to method call, expected, 1, have 21

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, nsstring, arguments, nsarray

When I use this code, Xcode gives me an error:

```
NSArray *buttonsFiles = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"button_plus.png",@"button_minus.png",@"button_multiple.png",@"button_div.png",@"button_eq.png",@"button_percent.png",@"button_sqrt.png",@"button_back.png",@"button_pointer.png",@"button_c.png",@"button_0.png",@"button_1.png",@"button_2.png",@"button_3.png",@"button_4.png",@"button_5.png",@"button_6.png",@"button_7.png",@"button_8.png",@"button_9.png",nil];
```

Should I use this instead to avoid the error?

```
NSString *myfile1 = [@"button_plus.png"];
NSString *myfile2 = [@"button_minus.png"];
...
NSString *myfile20 = [@"button_9.png"];
NSArray* myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myfile1, myfile2... myfile20r, nil];
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I think NSString *myfile1 = [@"button_plus.png"]; this might be the problem. Try NSString *myfile1 = @"button_plus.png"; and check.

Answer (score 5):

The method you need is `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]`, not `[NSArray arrayWithObject:]`

Note the plural **Objects**.

Comment: Oh, i don't saw that! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped, please consider accepting it using the green tick under the voting buttons.

Answer (score 4):

it should be `-[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]` you forgot '**s**'